# How to use MongoRepository In or All operator

Tags: mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I need to fetch list of data from collection by using MongoRepository without using @Query.

I tried like below in my repository.

List findByFirstNameAll(Set firstName);

But when I give like above getting error like **Invalid derived query! No property all found for type String! Traversed path:**

But if I define a method with In its not complaining.

List findByFirstNameIn(Set firstName);

I need to use MongoDB All operator instead of In.